# GA4 - Engagement menu not visible

Tags: google-analytics-4

Why is the `Engagement` menu not visible in my analytics?

I want to find the `Bounce rate`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking at is a [Collection](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10460557?hl=en). In simple words, GA4 admins can create a custom left-side navigation bar with the collection of reports and headings they wish the Report users to see.

If you are an Admin you can go to the `Library` settings at the bottom left and select / edit the left side nav bar. You can alter it and show Engagement collection.

[image]

[image]